# Is there a way to get a more descriptive error message from GCC?

Tags: gcc

so instead of printing for example:

```
cannot find -lGL
```

print:

```
cannot find -lGL, expected location: [ /foo/lib , /bar/lib ]
```

(and likewise with header files)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `-v` (verbose) option to the command-line, you will get ample information.  Here is an example:

```
GNU assembler version 2.22 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.22
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'foo' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=both -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o foo /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../.. /var/tmp/ccKveaGH.o -lNoSuchGL -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNoSuchGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `LIBRARY_PATH` lists the directories which are searched, and the linker command `collect2` shows the actual command-line.